# Figuring out why I am getting a Resource ID #5 error

Tags: php

This is a part of my code, and the echo is to test the value and it gives me Resource ID #5

```
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE firstname='$submittedfirstname' AND lastname='$submittedlastname' AND email='$submittedemail'") or die(mysql_error());
$counter = mysql_num_rows($id);
echo $id;
```

I am just getting into programming, and lately seeing lot of Resource ID outputs/errors while working with Databases.

Can someone correct the error in my code? And explain me why it isnt giving me the required output?

Comment: If you're just getting into programming, you shouldn't learn the mysql_* functions. Learn PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: I had this but it was because I had an old print_r($my->adapter) in my code.  I commented it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an error. This is similar to when you try to print an array without specifying an index, and only the string "Array" is printed. You can access the actual data contained within that resources (which you can think of as a collection of data) using functions like mysql_fetch_array().

In fact, if there were an error here, the value of $id would not be a resource. I usually use the is_resource() function to verify that everything is alright before using variables which are supposed to contain a resource.

I guess what you intend to do is this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE firstname='$submittedfirstname' AND lastname='$submittedlastname' AND email='$submittedemail'") or die(mysql_error());
if(is_resource($result) and mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row["id"];
    }
```

Comment: Understood 90% of what you said.

Since I am taking only single field (i.e id) and assigning it to $id, I cant understand where the error is. Ofcourse taken the point when dealing with taking out all fields.

Curious whats the right code I should be using here.

Comment: You know that it's a single field, but the function doesn't. It will treat the resource the same way whether it has 0 rows or a 1000. I have added some code, which fetches one single row (the first one if there are multiple rows in the result, which we can be assured there will _not_ be) from the resource and printing the value of the id column in that row.

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean to `echo $counter`?  `$id` is a resource because [`mysql_query()` returns a resource](http://php.net/mysql_query).

If you are trying to get the value of the `id` column from the query, you want to use e.g., [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array).

Here is an excerpt from http://php.net/mysql.examples-basic:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

// Printing results in HTML
echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Adapted to the code you provided, it might look something like this:

```
$result =
  mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE firstname='$submittedfirstname' AND lastname='$submittedlastname' AND email='$submittedemail' LIMIT 1")
    or die(mysql_error());

if( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
{
  $id = $row['id'];
}
else
{
  // No records matched query.
}
```

Note in my code that I also added `LIMIT 1` to the query, as it seems like you are only interested in fetching a single row.

Comment: I echoed $id to see what the string in id was,when I saw Resource Id #5 being saved to my db in the later part of the codes. So I was looking where the fault was, and echoed $id, and it says Resource Id #5.

$counter is for rest of the code Phoenix. 

Really want to know where I am making the mistake :)

Comment: Bit more complicated than I thought.I will start adapting it from now on.

Thanks for the quick response and explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($id)) {
 echo $row['id'];
}
```

?

Comment: Pretty much yes, but I need the value of field id, only when the firstname, lastname and email matches the respective fields in the table.

Answer (score 0):

$kode_gel = substr($_GET['gel'],0,3);
$no_gel = substr($_GET['gel'],3,5);

```
$cek = mysql_query("SELECT id_arisan 
                    FROM arisan WHERE kode_gel = '".$kode_gel."'
                    AND no_gel = '".$no_gel."'");
       $result = mysql_fetch_array($cek);
       $id = $result['id_arisan'];
   header("location: ../angsuran1_admin.php?id=".$id);
```