# Getting a Serialized Array From a MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

So I have a table in my database called "cards", in this table there is a column called "decks" which needs to contain a list of serials numbers of various decks.  Since cards can belong to multiple decks an array is needed to store the multiple serial numbers.  I was told the best way to store an array in a MySQL database was to serialize it.  However when I attempt to retrieve the serialized data with this code:

```
$serialized_decks = mysql_query("SELECT `decks` FROM `cards` WHERE serial = '".$content[$b]."'")or die(mysql_error());
    echo $serialized_decks;
```

I get this message:

> Resource id #5

Anyone got any ideas or tips?

Also I did find this article but the solution did not help me: [Figuring out why I am getting a Resource ID #5 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754320/figuring-out-why-i-am-getting-a-resource-id-5-error)

Comment: First: I hope that your content does not come from some user input. It is very dangerous to use mysql_query and the function will be removed in the future: http://www.php.net/mysql_query. Try var_dump($serialized_decks); and you might see more. ;-)

Comment: The accepted answer on the question you linked to is pretty much the answer to your question, actually. TL;DR: the function gives you a resultset. You have to call another function to fetch the data from the resultset.

Comment: Have you tried retrieve the array into PHP and unserialize it?